# Negative charges in acid-catalyzed reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

Whenever my professor draws a mechanism in an acid-catalyzed reaction, he always says you can't form negative charges. Why is that?

Comment: Well, with all those greedy $\rm H^+$ skulking around, any negative charge won't last long.

Comment: Similarly, reactions in alkalic environment do not produce $\ce{H+}$

Answer (score 1):

The acidic environment would not allow creation of anions but anions of strong acids, that are too weak bases to be significantly protonated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind your professor's statement is that when you have an acidic solution, the H<sup>+</sup> is always around, and therefore it quickly reacts with any negative charges that it meets. That's why you can't have any negative charges, they won't last long!

Remember that proton exchange is among the fastest chemical reactions too. I hope this helps!